# Install two separate KongHQ in same kube deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kong, kong-ingress

I am following [this procedure](https://konghq.com/blog/kubernetes-ingress-api-gateway/) to deploy konghq in my Kubernetes.

The key installation command there is this:

```
$ kubectl create -f https://konghq.com/blog/kubernetes-ingress-api-gateway/
```

It works fine when I create one single kinghq deployment. But it doesn't work for two deployments. What would I need to do? I changed the namespace but realized that about of resources are created outside of the namespace.

Answer (score 1):

There is no sense to create 2 ingress controllers under 1 namespace. Would you like have multiple ingress rules under 1 namespace  - you are welcome to create 1 Ingress controller and multiple rules.

Consider creating 2 ingress controllers in case you have multiple namespaces.
For example, check [Multiple Ingress in different namespaces](https://github.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/issues/960#)

> I am trying to setup 2 Ingress controllers in my k8s cluster under 2
> namespaces. Reason for this setup: Need one to be public which has
> route to only one service that we want to expose. Need another one to
> be private and has routes to all services including the internal
> services

To deep dive into your issue it would be nice to have logs, errors, etc.

In case you still DO need 2 controllers, I would recommend you change namespace resource limits(to avoid issues) and then try deploy again.

To check: [Multiple kong ingress controller or just one to different environments](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/multiple-kong-ingress-controller-or-just-one-to-different-environments/5778)